# ocultar cadena de conexion wn windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, encriptación, app.config

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion windows forms con conexion a base de datos en un servidor de internet, tengo la cadena de conexion situada en el archivo app.config y necesito poder mantener esa cadena de conexion fuera del alcance del usuario final.
He investigado un poco y lo que he encontrado a sido la encriptacion en tiempo de ejecucion de la seccion connectionString, pero eso me deja la vulnerabilidad de que si abren el fichero app.config antes de ejecutar el programa la primera vez pueden ver la cadena en texto plano, he revisado los metodos RSA/DAPI que vienen incluidos en .net pero no logro el resultado esperado.
Lo q espero es crear algun tipo de instalador que en el proceso de instalacion encripte dicha cadena.
saludos y disculpen si no hay codigo pero es que la pregunta no es de codigo como tal